# Galaxy s4 remove icon doesn't work

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

i have problem with my galaxy s4 i9500 (android version 4.3)
Shortly - when i drop my app icon on trash nothing happens.

More info - I can't to remove apps with desktop remove trash, tap and move app icon on the trash icon from desktop and apps is not remove, just icon, why? with my another galaxy s4 i can to remove like that.
i can to remove just from settings (app manager).

p.s. sorry for my english

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking: Do you want to uninstall the app or just remove the shortcut? The trash can should remove the shortcut from a home screen. You need to open the app drawer and drag it to `Uninstall` to uninstall.

Comment: i want to uninstall app(from homescreen trash), but i can uninstall just shortcut.

Comment: Yes, that's what the transcan does for a home screen. You need to open the app drawer and drag it to uninstall it.

Comment: i dragged app on trash of homescreen, but nothing happen. when i drag system app(msgs, contacts and ...) trash icon also showed(on my another device it doesn't show, because system app can't delete)

Comment: So the shortcut stays on the home screen? It isn't meant to uninstall from there.

Comment: when i try to remove shortcuts - all working nice, but when i try to remove app like that(drag app on trash of homescreen) nothing happen, but my another device too samsung s4, when i drop app on trash icon of homescreen, device prompt DELETE APP OR NOT.

Comment: Different devices do it differently. With the S4: Drag from HOMESCREEN: Remove shortcut. THAT'S IT! Drag from App Drawer: Uninstall.

Comment: i know it :) but drag from app drawer doesn't work, after drop app on trash icon(with "remove" text) nothing happen. i need to go to settings, and in apps manager to do it(uninstall).
but on my another s4 device all it's working nice(drag from app drawer for uninstall and remove shortcuts too)

Comment: @IceJOKER What's different between the two devices?

Comment: @DanHulme android version . I'll try to upgrade to kitkat

Comment: After upgrade os all is working nice ))